# Convert void* representation of a dword to wstring

Tags: c++, windows, atl

I am having dumb monday so my apologies for posting such a newbie-like question.

I am using [CRegKey.QueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k07tc8k5(v=VS.80).aspx) to return a dword value from the registry.  QueryValue writes the value into `void* pData` and the length into `ULONG* pnBytes`.

Now there is a way of getting it from pData into a wstring probably via stringstream.  The closest I came was getting the result as a hex string. I was about to work on converting the hex representation to a dword and then from there to a wstring when I decided that was just dumb and ask on here instead of wasting another hour of my life on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use CRegKey::QueryDWORDValue instead?
Then you could just swprintf_s to print it into a string (if you wish to).

Comment: How would I know that it was a DWORD ahead of time?

Comment: If you know the name of the key, you should probably also know the data type.

Comment: If you don't know, then you'll have to use CRegKey::QueryValue, check if the value type is REG_DWORD, and then you can just cast the pData member into a DWORD e.g. DWORD x = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(pData);

Comment: And then convert the dword with: `std::wstringstream ss;
 ss << value;
 return ss.str();`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test but should be fine:

```
/* To test if the value is REG_DWORD and get it */
DWORD dwValue;
switch (key->QueryDWORDValue(lpName, &dwValue)) {
    case ERROR_SUCCESS:
        cout << "All ok, value: " << dwValue;
        break;

    case ERROR_INVALID_DATA:
        cout << "Error, not DWORD value";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Some other error";
        break;
}

/* to obtain the type */
DWORD dwType;
if (key->QueryValue(lpName, &dwType, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)) /* use 'dwType' here... */
```